# Convert List to Set to group by a an attribute using Java Stream

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have a `list` of object `Car` which has two attributes
`int carId, long carSN`

```
1, 123
2, 456
3, 123
1, 789
```

And I have another `set` of object `CarCombined` which has two attributes `int carId, Set<Long> carSNs`

Is there a way in Java Language using Java Stream (preferably) I can convert that `List<Car>` to `Set<CarCombined>` such that it groups by the carId? the new `Set<CarCombined>` I am looking for should have these values:

```
1, [123, 789]
2, [456]
3, [123]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting list to set using java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904070/converting-list-to-set-using-java-8)

Comment: I think you might have a better time using a `Map<Integer, Set<Long>>`, since it would let you deal with the `Set<Long>` per `carId` directly. That would be a direct `list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c.carId, Collectors.toSet()));`

Comment: Can I start with converting it to ```Map<Integer, Set<Long>>``` then convert map to my Set ?

Comment: also this ```Collectors.toSet()``` will collect the entire Car object not the carSN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
list.stream().collect(groupingBy(Car::getCarId,  mapping(Car::getCarSn, toSet())))
        .entrySet().stream().map(e-> new CarCombined(e.getKey(), e.getValue())).collect(toSet());
```

First you transform your list into `Map<carId, Set<carSn>>` and then transform map into `CarCombined` objects and collect them as Set